# Nasm: Problem in duplicate a bmp image and make it white

Tags: assembly, nasm

The objective of this program is with an image given as an argument to create a copy of it but all white, but whenever it runs the problem gives the error `errMsgOpenBmp`, `Erro ao abrir o BMP`. I believe the problem is in the way I use the buffer, `readImgBuffer`, and the `writeImageFile` function.

```
section .data

    NULL                equ 0
    LF                  equ 10
    STDOUT              equ 1
    SYS_read            equ 0 
    SYS_open            equ 2 
    O_RDONLY            equ 000000q 
    SYS_close           equ 3 
    EXIT_SUCCESS        equ 0
    SYS_creat           equ 85
    SYS_exit            equ 60
    S_IRUSR             equ 00400q
    S_IWUSR             equ 00200q
    MAX_IMG_SIZE        equ 1048576
    SYS_write           equ 1
    bmpFileDesc         dq  0
    newImage            db  'fname.bmp',0x00
    newLine             db LF,NULL
    errMsgOpenTxt       db "Erro ao abrir o TXT", LF, NULL
    errMsgOpenBmp       db "Erro ao abrir o BMP", LF, NULL
    errMsgRead          db "Erro ao ler o BMP", LF, NULL
    errMsgWrite         db "Error write", LF, NULL



section .bss

    readImgBuffer: resb MAX_IMG_SIZE
    newBmpFileDesc: resq 1



section .text

printStr:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push rbx
    mov rbx, rdi
    mov rdx, 0
strCountLoop:
    cmp byte [rbx], NULL
    je strCountDone
    inc rdx
    inc rbx
    jmp strCountLoop
strCountDone:
    cmp rdx, 0
    je prtDone
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rsi, rdi
    mov rdi, STDOUT 
    syscall  
prtDone:
    pop rbx
    pop rbp
    ret


printStrLn:
    call printStr
    mov rdi, newLine
    call printStr
    ret


errorOnOpenBmp:
    mov rdi, errMsgOpenBmp
    call printStrLn
    call terminate
    
    
errorOnRead:
    mov rdi, errMsgRead
    call printStrLn
    call terminate
    

errorOnWrite:
    mov rdi, errMsgWrite
    call printStr
    call terminate


terminate:
    mov rax, SYS_exit
    mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
    syscall


readImageFile:
    push rsi    
    mov rax, SYS_open
    mov rsi, O_RDONLY
    syscall
    cmp rax,0
    jl errorOnOpenBmp 
    mov [bmpFileDesc], rax
    mov rax, SYS_read
    mov rdi, qword [bmpFileDesc]
    pop rsi 
    mov rsi, readImgBuffer
    mov rdx, MAX_IMG_SIZE
    syscall
    cmp rax,0
    jl errorOnRead
    push rax 
    mov rax, SYS_close
    mov rdi, qword [bmpFileDesc]
    syscall 
    pop rax
    ret
   
   
changeColorToWhite:
    _for: 
        cmp ebx, MAX_IMG_SIZE  
        jb _ciclo 
        jmp _next          
    _ciclo:
        mov byte [ebx + 0], 0xFF 
        mov byte [ebx + 1], 0xFF 
        mov byte [ebx + 2], 0xFF  
        add ebx, 4
        jmp _for
    _next:
        ret 
          
          
writeImageFile:
    push rsi
    push rdx
    mov rax, SYS_creat
    mov rdi, [newImage]
    mov rsi, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR
    syscall
    cmp rax,0
    jl errorOnOpenBmp
    mov [bmpFileDesc], rax
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rdi, qword [bmpFileDesc]
    pop rdx 
    pop rsi
    syscall
    cmp rax, 0
    jl errorOnWrite
    mov rax, SYS_close
    mov rdi, qword [bmpFileDesc]
    syscall 
    ret     



global _start 
_start: 

    
    mov rdi, [rsp + 16]
    call readImageFile
    
    mov ebx, readImgBuffer
    
    call changeColorToWhite
    
    mov rdi, readImgBuffer
    
    call writeImageFile  
    
    
    pop rax
    call terminate
```

- The `readImageFile` function aims to open the bmp file and store its information in a buffer.
- The `writeImageFile` function aims to create a new image and write the info from the buffer in the new bmp file.

Comment: Verify whatever file you passed as argument exists, is in the correct place and is readable. Run the program through `strace`. Works here as far as opening the file is concerned. PS: the `push rsi` / `pop rsi` in `readImageFile` does not seem to be useful.

Comment: Try to do as following and see what happens: ```mov rax,2 ;   sys_open``` ```mov rdi,fileName ;   const char *filename``` ```mov rsi,[fileFlags] ;   int flags``` ```mov rdx,[fileMode] ;   int mode``` ```syscall```